# scipy.signal.convolve flips axis in result when using 'same'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, convolution

I'm using scipy.signal.convolve to apply a simple filter to a grayscale picture
My inputs are as follows:
kk -> filer (2x2)
im -> image (500x800) opened via pillow

```
>>> from scipy.signal import convolve as cv
>>> kk
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
>>> im.size
(500, 800)
>>> cvRes = cv(im,kk,'same')
```

When I apply the convolution, I was expecting the result to be in a shape of (500,800), i.e. same as the input image (im), but the results are in shape of (800,500).

```
>>> cvRes = cv(im,kk,'same')
>>> cvRes.shape
(800, 500)
```

I'm a bit confused regarding this output, I think I maybe missing something or misunderstanding how the library is supposed to work.
Appreciate any help in regards to how to get a non flipped output and if I can just flip the x/y when trying to get the value of single pixel?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also getting the same result when using convolve2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a side effect of PIL.  A PIL image with size (800,500) has 500 rows of 800 columns.  When that becomes a numpy array, it has a shape of (500,800).  So, it's not that the array is being transposed, it's that the two modules number the axes differently.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that explains it. Would transposing the image before convolution be a good idea?

Comment: No.  Remember, these aren't transposed.  It's 500 rows of 800 columns.  PIL notates that as (800,500) because that's how we think of bitmaps.  Numpy notates that as (500,800).  You just need to make sure your convolution matrix is the same: rows of columns, not (x,y).

Comment: so just using a flipped pair of coordinates will do the trick when reading the output np array, i.e use `cvRes[y,x]` instead of `cvRes[x,y]` ... if I got your point right, that is :)

Comment: RIght.  In numpy, the first axis is "rows", which is the y coordinate in image thinking.

Comment: thanks a lot Tim, really appreciate your help :)